# How to change the brick size for renko bars?

Tags: pine-script

In my strategy i use renko bars. I'd like to change bricks size when there's flat market. I know about security() function to make multiple timeframe strategies. However renko bars don't use time but magnitude of the price. How can i change the magnitude of a brick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are calculating your own Renko bricks, you can't. If you are not calculating your own bricks, you should not be trading a strategy on Renko charts. See here for an explanation why: [Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts: Caution! - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I should access the brokerage api directly to calculate my own bricks?

Comment: If by "my strategy" you mean a Pine strategy, then you should follow the recommendations in the link's doc and do your own Renko calls, but run the strategy on a normal chart to get realistic fill prices.